# How to setup continuous DB replication from on-prem MS SQL server to PostgreSQL on AWS RDS without reconfiguring source machine?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am looking for a way to set up continuous data replication between an on-prem **Microsoft SQL Server** to AWS RDS PostgreSQL. The source table is updated **once every 24 hours**. The challenge here is that I don't have any control over the source (on-prem) DB. All I have is a DB user that I can use to query the database. In a nutshell, I am looking for the following requirements:

- The source machine should not be modified in any way (i.e. applying configurations to the source machine)
- Cheap (do not require a migration server to run 24/7) and easy to manage (set up once and forget it)
- Ideally, the solution should only migrate the changes done to the source DB table such as adding/removing records. In other words, avoid emptying the target table and re-filling it with the source table records (that is what the AWS DMS "**Full-Load**" would do)

I was looking at AWS DMS Ongoing Replication but it requires changes to the source machine so I had to dismiss that solution (see [*Using a Microsoft SQL Server database as a source for AWS DMS*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.CDC)). Also, that solution would require a "*Replication Instance*" to run 24/7.

Is there anything else I should be looking at that satisfy the above requirements? Or my only option would be to go with "Full-Load" AWS DMS migration which would be potentially costly solution provided the frequency of updates to the source database table?

Comment: Can the Postgres server access SQL Server instance? If yes, you could use a foreign table from Postgres to SQL Server and use a materialized view to have a cached copy on the Postgres side. Or - if the connection is fast enough - maybe you don't need to "cache" (replicate) anything. Getting tds_fdw to work might be quite tricky though if that is a managed environment. Or you could look into https://debezium.io/ which claims it can replicate using CDC.

Comment: Thank you for the soltuon @a_horse_with_no_name. In our case, it would be nessary to cache the data as the source table/database often break. That is actually the reason I am investigating a solution that would serve as a "stop-gap" database and our app will use that instead.

I don't have a lot of PostfreSQL exerience. Would I be able to refresh on-demand that cached view when using the above Foreign Table + Materialized view approach?

I will look at debezium.io, thank you.

Comment: "*Would I be able to refresh on-demand that cached view*" - yes

Comment: Thank you. I will have to exeriment with Foreign Tables + Materialized views and see if it will be viable approach for my usecase. Also, I had a breaf look at debezium.io and it seems that it also requires a small but necessary change to the source DB which in my case would not be possible (the `sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` commands needs to eb executed on the source db).

Comment: Currently your source does not tell you what changed. Or does it? You need to go through all of the source tables and see if there is a usable date field. Then you can possibly have a mix of full loads for small tables and "windowed" or "high water mark" loads for large tables (load all records that have a transaction date in the last week)

Comment: any ongoing(continuos) replication needs CDC feature on the source DB and in SQL server, v 2016 and about supports CDC from the standard edition, but lower versions need enterprise edition. As @Nick.McDermaid said, try daily incremental loads if you have a PK column and updated_at timestamp column, but it won't replicate the deletes. For that you need CDC or enable triggers(the worst idea) to capture the PK for the deleted rows then after the incremental load, delete the rows on the target.

Comment: I agree - deletes are a problem for any hand coded replication solution, you need to enable some kind of cdc tracking in the source. But this is not an option for you